# AWS EC2 Target Tracking Scaling Policies - Scaling multiple instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am exploring AWS EC2 autoscaling with target tracking and custom metrics. From the documents I understand that when a particular target is hit, an autoscale event is triggered that either scales in or out the EC2 instance.

I followed the instructions as provided by the terraform docs for [aws_autoscaling_policy](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_policy.html#target_tracking_configuration) and is working, but this is scaling in and out just one instance.

Now, for my use-case, i want to scale in and out two instances. Is there a way to do this with target tracking scaling policy?

Any help, much appreciated.

Following is a working policy written in terraform for target tracking with custom metrics.

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "target-tracking-autoscale" {

name = "target-traclking-policy"

autoscaling_group_name = "target-tracking-asg"
policy_type            = "TargetTrackingScaling"

target_tracking_configuration {
    customized_metric_specification {
        metric_dimension {
            name  = "asg"
            value = "custom-value"
        }

        metric_name = "CUSTOM_METRIC"
        namespace   = "CUSTOM-METRIC/NAMESPACE"
        statistic   = "Average"
        }
        target_value = "2"
    }
}
```

Regards.

---

**Update 1**

I have tried adding the `step_adjustment` but this parameter is exclusively for step scaling. Terraform throws this following error:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* module.pt-wowza.aws_autoscaling_policy.target-tracking-autoscale: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_autoscaling_policy.target-tracking-autoscale: step_adjustment is only supported for policy type StepScaling

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant bits of your terraform script?  Perhaps it's just a case of adding [`scaling_adjustment`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_policy.html#scaling_adjustment)?

Comment: @James Thorpe : Yes I have tried adding scaling_adjustment to aws_autoscaling_policy but scaling_adjustment is allowed only for StepScaling policy. Terraform throws an error. Updated the question with the error.

Comment: Why do you want to use target tracking over step scaling adjustments? Target tracking is for saying try to make my service scale up so that it reduces the metric to this value. So this might be to target 75% average CPU usage across the service, adding tasks until it falls below this and removing them until it hits this. Telling it to add 2 tasks at a time doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: That is exactly what I want to do. I want to keep the overall average of my custom metric at a value of say 2. Now I need to scale in and out 2 instances since one will act as master and the other as slave.

Comment: It might be better if you explain what metric you are using and what your application is doing because this seems confusing without an understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: This is the setup : Master receives requests for a task, performs some initial computations and delegates the actual workload to its slave and the slave does rest of the computation. My custom metric is number of requests served by the master. If it is above a particular value, I would want to scale-up the master and slave together. There may be multiple slaves in future for a single master and the custom metric value will change accordingly. I can't spin up containers/ecs tasks for slaves as the slave tasks require accelerated computing instances.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and was able to fix it by adding `policy_type` attribute to the scaling policy resource

```
policy_type = "TargetTrackingScaling"
```

```
policy_type - (Optional) The policy type, either "SimpleScaling", "StepScaling", "TargetTrackingScaling", or "PredictiveScaling". If this value isn't provided, AWS will default to "SimpleScaling."
```